# How to declare a local variable and give it the value of the first row of a temptable ? (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure on sql server, in this procedure I have a temp_table that contains only one row and I would like to declare a local variable in that procedure and give it the value in the temp_table :

Let's suppose my temp_table has one row and 2 columns :

Variable       Variable2

"hello_world"        3

I tried  `Declare @variable varchar(50) = #temp_table.variable`

but unsurprisingly it's not working.

I would like that line of code to put the value "hello_world" in the local variable @variable.

Do you know how to do that without using a subquery select top 1 if it's possible ?

Comment: I get the feeling that the RHS of your assignment should perhaps be a scalar, not a temp table.

Comment: You don't need an explicit `TOP` but you do need a `SELECT`, no way around that. `DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT variable FROM #temp_table)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(50) = (SELECT variable FROM #temp_table);
```

What's "good" about this approach is that, if for some reason you are mistaken about the table having only one row, the query will error out:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,
>   >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

And that's arguably exactly what you want. Using `TOP(1)` with no `ORDER BY` or a separate `SELECT @variable = variable ...` will select one *arbitrary* value from the table -- that might be harmless, or then again it might be a really hard to debug issue.

Answer (score 2):

If your table only has one row, you can use:

```
  Declare @variable varchar(50)

    SELECT  @variable = variable from #temp_table
```

But if your table has multiple rows you need to use order by as well and fetch the top 1 value

```
SELECT TOP 1 @variable = variable from #temp_table order by col -- col is the column for which you want the top value
```

Comment: `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`? `TOP 1` according to which order?

Comment: @Sami the op mentioned "I have a temp_table that contains only one row"

Comment: @ShikharArora The OP says _"Let's suppose"_ it's just a sample. And if it's one row why even we need `TOP`?